# SAS macros: Strange behavior of quotes

Tags: sas, macros

I'm learning SAS and write this macro:

```
  %macro firstMacro(mvLO, OLO);
    %local Count;
    %local Wordy;
    %local Resty;
        %let Resty = '';
        %let Count = %sysfunc( count( &OLO, %str( ) ) );
        %let Wordy = %sysfunc( scan(&OLO, 1 ,%str( ) ) );
        %let Wordy = "&Wordy";
        %let Resty = &Wordy;
        %put &Resty;
        /*strange behavior here*/
    %DO I=2 %TO &Count+1;       
        %let Wordy = %sysfunc(scan(&OLO, &I ,%str( ) ));
        %let Wordy = "&Wordy";
        %put Wordy is;
        %put &Wordy;
        %let Resty = %sysfunc(cats(&Resty, %str(,), &Wordy));
        %put &Resty;
    %END;
        %put FINAL OUT;
        %put &Resty;        
  %mend firstMacro;
```

and calling it:

```
  %firstMacro(mvLO=WORK, OLO=field_1 field_2 field_3);
```

and see this output:

```
  FINAL OUT
  "field_1""field_2","field_3
```

So, I ask SAS:
why did you eat my comma (`,`) between `field_1` and `field_2`?

Comment: Can you say what you're trying to do with this macro?

Comment: yes, i'm trying to make this:
       `"field_1","field_2","field_3"`. After this macro i can use this string for IN-clause in Where in macro. When i trying to use string without quotes `field_1,field_2,field_3` in macro in WHERE with IN, i get error

Comment: This line `%DO I=2 %TO &Count+1;` is the culprit I think. Try `%DO I=2 %TO %EVAL(&Count+1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you replace this

```
%let Resty = %sysfunc(cats(&Resty, %str(,), &Wordy));
```

with this

```
%Let RESTY=&resty %str(,) &wordy;
```

it will work (at least with your sample call)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to learn SAS.  Here's a shorter macro to do the same sort of thing.

```
%macro firstMacro(mvLO, OLO);
    %local str1 str2 str3;
    %let str1=%sysfunc( strip(%sysfunc(compbl(&OLO))));
    %let str2=%sysfunc( transtrn(&str1,%str( ),%str(, ) )) ;
    %let str3=%sysfunc( catq(2csa, &str2));
    %put &str3;
 %mend firstMacro;
 %firstMacro(mvLO=WORK, OLO=field_1 field_2 field_3);
```

On log

```
"field_1","field_2","field_3"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like loops (and who doesn't):

```
%macro firstMacro(mvLO=, OLO=);

   %* Note we dont need to make those macrovariables local in a macro - they;
   %* should be local to the macro unless you specifically make them global;

   %* Get a counter started ;
   %let i = 1;

   %* Initiate your new string to be empty;
   %let resty = ;

   %* Loop over your inputs until there are none left *;  
   %do %until(%scan(&OLO, &i) = );    

      %* Add the quotes and the comma;
      %let resty = &resty "%scan(&OLO, &i)", ;

      %* Update the counter;
      %let i = %eval(&i + 1);
   %end;

   %* Get rid of that trailing comma;
   %let resty = %substr(%nrbquote(&resty, 1, %eval(%length(&resty) - 1));

   %* Output to the log;
   %put &resty;
%mend;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use qsysfunc in place of sysfunc